# Hide/ Show notification bar in android

Tags: android, notifications

I am able to hide notification bar using this code

```
setWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But I want the user to have an option to show and hide notification bar. 
Currently my `Activity` permanently hides the notification bar.

How cam I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit full screen mode (i.e. show status bar) by using:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: i try your code. getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

this line is perfact but above line dosent hide notification

Comment: Both lines meant to be used **together**